# Ubuntu 22.04 doesn’t detect graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04

So I have a desktop with Ubuntu, and my graphics card is a GeForce GTX 1060. I switched from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 about a week ago, and haven’t had any problems at all - until yesterday. It was then that my computer froze, seemingly randomly.

Nothing was responding for like 10 minutes, so I turned it off by holding down the power button, and then turned it back on again.

Upon booting up though, I noticed that everything was significantly slower. Looking at Additional Drivers revealed that the list of drivers was completely gone, along with any mention of the GPU.

I tried updating the drivers with `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, but to no avail - it just says that all the drivers are up-to-date.

Running `sudo lshw -C display` didn’t seem to detect the nvidia card either. Instead it listed a UHD Graphics 630, which I guess is the... backup graphics card or something?

At this point I’m not sure what to do. Has anyone here dealt with this before? What might cause Ubuntu to forget about the graphics card, and is there any way to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I just booted from a live usb with Ubuntu 20.04, which seemed to recognize the graphics card just fine. So it's not a hardware issue, thankfully. I guess it's something specific to my current installation?

I'd *really* rather not reinstall the OS though, if I have any choice. Also I have no idea if the bug is version-specific, so it's possible I might encounter it *again* in 20.04 anyway. Which would mean I'd reinstalled for nothing.

Here's the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #12 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H310 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 04)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Just booted again from the same live usb as before, and this time the problem did *not* go away. No nvidia card to be found, and no drivers in Additional Drivers. The only other issue I encountered was that the disc-check at the beginning ended with "found 23 errors on your system", before proceeding to the installation menu. Maybe it's correlated?

But anyway, now I'm back to having exactly 0 solutions. I have no idea how to proceed. Any more help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 3:**

output of `sudo grep -iE "nvidia|VGA" /var/log/dmesg`:

```
[    0.448147] kernel: pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: setting as boot VGA device
[    0.448147] kernel: pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.448147] kernel: pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
[    0.448147] kernel: vgaarb: loaded
[    0.588440] kernel: fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[    4.479544] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1663111896.388:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=663 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.479564] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1663111896.388:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=663 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.616337] kernel: fb0: switching to i915 from EFI VGA
[    4.616465] kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    4.618206] kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
```

Comment: UHD Graphics 630 is Intel integrated graphics (built-in to your CPU). Is the graphics card itself perhaps broken or something like that? At the very least Ubuntu should be able to recognize that it's connected.

Comment: Please add output of `lspci` to your question.

Comment: Well it can't be broken, since Ubuntu 20.04 seems to recognize it. I'd imagine if I booted from a live 22.04 usb, it would recognize the card as well, since this version worked fine when I first installed.

Comment: Also, edited to include the output of lspci

Comment: including relevant lines of dmesg / syslog might help too, for example `sudo grep -iE "nvidia|VGA" /var/log/dmesg`

Comment: cool, edited to include

Answer (score 0):

So I retract my claim that it couldn't be a hardware issue, because I think it's definitely a hardware issue.

Just now figured out that the big circuit board with a fan that you plug hdmis into is in fact, the nvidia gpu. I wiggled it around and now everything works fine, and I feel stupid.

It does look kind of slightly bent/lopsided though, like it's sagging from only being attached from 2 adjacent sides. Is it normal for graphics cards to overhang so much? Maybe that's really just how it's supposed to fit. Kinda worries me though